# How modify objects across scopes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, the notion of scopes really confuses me. I have a situation where I want to modify a an object or a variable from different scopes. Here is why: 
in my application I want to centralize the user notification Controller and notification view.
In the middle top of the page. I separate my code as follow: each view has its controller I think its fair reasonable. I want to inject a service or some common object that when invoking its function with some string parameter on a common place but, I figured out that I can not inject $scope service. So, when

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to communicate between controllers. That is fairly easy to realize whit a service that can broadcast messages (or objects) between controllers.

There is a nice youtube about this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OALSkJGsRw

Comment: Thank you I will check it out late but, now its time to go :D

Comment: I watched the video. Honestly I don't like the way this communication is made because I have to put $scope.$on('someEvent',function(){}); In every one of my controllers. Moreover changing the name of an event is error prone.

Comment: You could also pass `$rootScope`along and use common properties and methods in `rootScope`

Comment: I am working on implementing a simple design pattern for this I will post it just in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

OK here what I have done in my application. I am a java programmer  and I used to work with [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)

In GWT ther is a very nice design pattern, to notify widgets across the application, called EventBus. In angular I tried to do something similar. Here is the code link in [gist](https://gist.github.com/4046379)